# The absolute uri cannot be resolved : Custom Tag Issue

Tags: aem

I am facing one problem when my code goes to publish. I have page in which i used a component with custom tag. It work fine in author, but when i replicate my code from author to publish it gives error like : `The absolute uri: http:||www.mysite.com/taglibs cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` . I have correctly replicated the my /apps/mysite folder on publish. But it gives error on publish but not on author.Any troubleshooting steps that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that bundle with your custom tag library was installed correctly on publish enviroment (via /system/console/bundles).

And, could you describe how you deploy your project on publish enviroment?

Comment: Yes, There can be two issue, One is dependencies not getting resolve on publish environment, and other can be namespace issue, so need to restart the server after deployment.